# How do i solve "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette" error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to write a basic selenium script but cannot past the below error. I am using geckodriver 0.34, firefox 122.0.1, python 3.8.10 and Selenium 4.17.2

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

#geckdriver 0.34
#firefox 122.0.1
#Selenium 4.17.2
#python 3.8.10

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
service = Service(executable_path='/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/bin/geckodriver')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=opts)
browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
print("done")
```

I recieve this error when running my script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/FPL/PlayerImport.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=opts)
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/**[redacted my name]**/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

Comment: Are you doing this in docker or no?

Comment: i am not using docker

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating WSL to WSL2. I dont know why this worked but it did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).